# fgetCsv Returning null values for csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file placed at path

```
#http://thevowapp.com/brandstore/values.csv

$f = fopen("http://thevowapp.com/brandstore/values.csv", "w+");  
if(!f)
{
    echo "Error";
}
$line = fgetcsv($f);
echo json_encode($line);
```

I am trying to parse it, however the fgetCsv keeps on returning null. What could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. You try to open a remote file with `w+` (write) access. Use `r` for read.
2. You check `f` (undefined constant)`. Use`$f`.
3. You don't loop `fgetcsv`, so you won't get more than the header line.

Try:

```
$f = fopen('http://thevowapp.com/brandstore/values.csv', 'r');
if(!$f) {
    echo 'Error';
    exit;
}

$out = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($f)) {
    $out[] = $line;
}

echo json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Remove the pretty print option when you're happy.